# Issue with Firebase Cloud Function for Razorpay Integration

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, razorpay

I'm in the process of integrating Razorpay for payments into my project. To handle server-side logic, I'm utilizing Firebase Functions. My project involves two Firebase Cloud Functions: `createOrder` and `processOrder`. The `createOrder` function executes successfully and returns the order ID, which is then passed as options to the `processOrder` function.. The `processOrder` function is where I'm encountering an error. Specifically, I'm getting an error related to the `rzp1.open()` line in the code.

I'm stuck at this point and need assistance in resolving the issue.

```
exports.processOrder = functions
    .region("asia-south1")
    .https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      cors(request, response, async () => {
        try {
          const {
            amount,
            orderID,
            name,
            contact,
            email, // Default to an empty string if not provided
            userUID,
          } = request.body;

          // Access the Razorpay API key from Firebase configuration
          const razorpayApiKey = functions.config().razorpay.key_id;

          const options = {
            key: razorpayApiKey,
            amount: amount,
            currency: "INR",
            name: "EasyPizy", // your business name
            order_id: orderID,
            callback_url: "127.0.0.1:5501/Account-Menu/order-history.html",
            prefill: {
              name: name, // your customer's name
              email: email,
              contact: contact,
            },
            theme: {
              color: "#ff6347",
            },
            modal: {
              confirm_close: true,
            },
            customer_id: userUID,
            remember_customer: true,
            hidden: {
              contact: true,
              email: true,
            },
            send_sms_hash: true,
          };

         const rzp1 = new Razorpay({
            key_id: functions.config().razorpay.key_id,
            key_secret: functions.config().razorpay.key_secret,
            options
          });

          


          rzp1.open();

          rzp1.on("payment.success", (response) => {
            // Payment success logic here
            console.log("Payment successful:", response);

            // Store the payment details in Firestore
            const paymentDetails = {
              razorpay_payment_id: response.razorpay_payment_id,
              razorpay_order_id: response.razorpay_order_id,
              razorpay_signature: response.razorpay_signature,
            };

            // Define the path to the Firestore document
            const orderDocumentPath = `users/${userUID}/orders/${orderID}`;

            // Get a Firestore reference to the document
            const orderDocRef = admin.firestore().doc(orderDocumentPath);

            // Set the payment details in Firestore
            orderDocRef
                .update(paymentDetails, {merge: true})
                .then(() => {
                  console.log("Payment details stored in Firestore.");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.error(
                      "Error storing payment details in Firestore:",
                      error,
                  );
                });

            // Send a success response to the client
            response.status(200).send("Payment successful");
          });

          rzp1.on("payment.error", async (error) => {
            // Payment error logic here
            console.error("Payment error:", error);

            // Send an error response to the client
            response.status(500).send("Payment error");

            // Update the status field in Firestore to "failed"
            const orderDocumentPath = `users/${userUID}/orders/${orderID}`;
            const orderDocRef = admin.firestore().doc(orderDocumentPath);

            try {
              await orderDocRef.update({status: "failed"}, {merge: true});
              console.log("Order status updated to 'failed' in Firestore.");
            } catch (updateError) {
              console.error(
                  "Error updating order status in Firestore:",
                  updateError,
              );
            }
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error processing the order:", error);
          // Send an error response to the client in case of any exception
          response.status(500).send("Error processing the order");
        }
      });
    });
```

I have followed the official documentation and recommendations, but I keep getting the following error in the Cloud Function logs:

```
Error processing the order: Error: `key_id` is mandatory
```

I have double-checked my Firebase configuration and the way I'm initializing Razorpay, but I can't figure out what's causing this error.

**Expected Behavior:**

The Razorpay payment modal should open & be processed without any errors.

My specific question is, How should I modify the `processOrder` function to correctly handle the creation of the Razorpay object, considering the `key_id`, `key_secret`, and `options` when initializing the Razorpay object?

I believe this modification is crucial to ensure the seamless processing of Razorpay payments. Any guidance or code examples illustrating the correct way to set up the Razorpay object in this context would be greatly appreciated.